# React component not running componentDidmount in my project, so I get error isEdit of undefined?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When I run my react-native component, I get the following error:

[image]

However, in the debugger in `constructor` and `componentWillmount` and render lifecycle, `isEdit` is `false`.

Only `componentDidmount` is not printing anything, so I think the component is not running `componentDidmount` lifecycle and I don't know the error reason for this.

```
constructor(props: IProps) {
    // isEdit: false

    super(props);
    // const {navigation} = this.props;
    props.navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => {
        return <HeaderRightBtn onSubmit={this.onSubmit} />;
      },
    });
  }
componentWillmount() {
    // isEdit: false
}
componentDidmount() {
    // isEdit of undefined
}
render() {
    // isEdit: false
    const {categorys, isEdit} = this.props;
    const {myCategorys} = this.state;
    const classifyGroup = _.groupBy(categorys, (item) => item.classify);
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.classifyName}>我的分类</Text>
        <View style={styles.classifyView}>
          <DragSortableView
            dataSource={myCategorys}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            sortable={isEdit}
            fixedItems={fixedItems}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            onDataChange={this.onDataChange}
            parentWidth={parentWidth}
            childrenWidth={itemWidth}
            childrenHeight={itemHeight}
            marginChildrenTop={margin}
            onClickItem={this.onClick}
          />
          {/* {myCategorys.map(this.renderItem)} */}
        </View>
        <View>
          {Object.keys(classifyGroup).map((classify) => {
            return (
              <View key={classify}>
                <Text style={styles.classifyName}>{classify}</Text>
                <View style={styles.classifyView}>
                  {classifyGroup[classify].map((item, index) => {
                    if (
                      myCategorys.find(
                        (selectedItem) => selectedItem.id === item.id,
                      )
                    ) {
                      return null;
                    }
                    return this.renderUnSelectedItem(item, index);
                  })}
                </View>
              </View>
            );
          })}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You’re spelling “componentDidMount”/“componentWillMount” incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Correct names of methods are
“componentDidMount()” and “UNSAFE_componentWillMount()” as per [componentdidmount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) and [unsafe_componentwillmount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) respectively.

Note that componentWillMount() is changed to UNSAFE_componentWillMount() as per the  [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount).

Comment: thanks, and other reason is `this`, `renderItem()` methods should be `() => {}` bind this

Comment: Okay, I think you can click an upvote or tick mark icon under the voting icons if my answer helps :)